# Android - does decodeResource scale the bitmap for screen density?

Tags: android

In Android development, will

```
Bitmap bmpNormal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.normal);
```

load the bitmap from the correct drawables-density folder, or do I need to manually scale it?

I haven't been able to test this in the emulator, only on my phone display and my wife's phone.  Each one yields a similar sized bitmap, even though I have ldpi and mdpi resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should provide the resources in all the folders
-ldpi
-mdpi
-hdpi
-xhdpi
Android will automatically customize it and use it in correct layouts.The resources provided should be of the correct sizes.Checkout this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).You can know how the android customizes the images in an app.You can also scale  bitmap and use it but its more complicated meathod.

Comment: how to scale the the image download from url, or load from the database..i need to scale the image to match for screen density, is there any way to do this,if so please share some link or sample code

Answer (score 0):

Yes a drawables density specific bitmap will be loaded.