# Loading images to different screen sizes and densities in game development?

Tags: android, image-scaling

The code below draws a square and circle on different screen sizes distance between images changes. It would be more messed up with actual bitmaps and different screen sizes and densities. Here is the code

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ShapeTest extends Activity {
class RenderView extends View {        
    Paint paint;

    public RenderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();            
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);            
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth()-1, canvas.getHeight()-1, paint);

        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(0xff00ff00);            
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, 40, paint);

        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(0x770000ff);
        canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, paint);
        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(new RenderView(this));
}
}
```

Here is a pic:
[image]

How should i proceed?

Comment: Why is not anyone answering? Should i explain it more or what? Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the bounds of your rectangle are not depending on the screen size.

```
canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, paint);
```

will draw in pixels.

What you need is an appropriate multiplier for the width, height, top and left. 
`(float)(height / width)` or `(float)(width / height)` - depending on wich is larger.

```
canvas.drawRect(leftOffset* ratio, topOffset * ratio, baseWidth * ratio, baseHeight * ratio, paint);
```

If you use real Bitmaps, you would also need to scale it to the correct size.

Comment: Yes, i could do that but if it were a png image of say an elephant what would i do?

Comment: @user3404195 First, get the bitmap using `BitmapFactory`. Then use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` to scale the Bitmap using the ratio. Now calculate the top/left you want to display the image, also using the ratio. **edit** but don't do the bitmap creation in onDraw. On draw is just for drawing

Answer (score 0):

I think this code gets the apropriately sized bitmap:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

according to this post:
[Android - does decodeResource scale the bitmap for screen density?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440782/android-does-decoderesource-scale-the-bitmap-for-screen-density)